# Configuring the google account programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

i need some help, i was trying configuring the google account behind the android, the main idea is don't use the wizard to configure the google account, i need do this by code, i was searching, but don't successfully, the only way I was trying to do was the following, but I believe that this is merely a way to make my current application tivese access the account I'm trying to use, but still without success

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
        AccountManager mgr = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account acc = new Account("sexo@gmail.com", "com.google");
        if(mgr.addAccountExplicitly(acc, "pass", new Bundle())) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
        Log.d("test", e.toString());
        e.getStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is my manifest used

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actteste"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permaission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:installLocation="internalOnly">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.company.demo.account.AuthenticatorService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to create a service and also reference in my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:accountType="com.company.demo.account.DEMOACCOUNT"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                   android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                   android:label="qualquer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the account manager to setup a new account on the Google server. It can only be used for login.

The Setup application in Android also has no API available for setting up a new account. The only real way would be to reverse engineer their application code and try to inject values. It not smart and here is why:

All of this is designed this way for customer safety and Google protection. When doing this in an automated way, the customer is not agreeing to the Terms and Conditions as well as creating an account with dangerous access to user information on the device or from the device itself.

If this is 100% required, I suggest that you have the device communicate to a server you own which handles the negotiations with Google and alerts the user accordingly. Its not what you may want to hear, but this is not an advisable route.